# Overriding default play project settings for changing the path of conf folder

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In `Build.scala` I am adding below lines to override the default path of the conf directory.

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
     resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://homes/.m2/repository",
     resolvers += "maven2 repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
     confDirectory <<= baseDirectory(_ / ".." / "conf")
  )
```

After doing clean, compile and run , when i am trying to load the page , its not taking the Messages file from new location.So it means its unable to locate the new conf path.

Kindly guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which version of Play/SBT are you using?

Comment: @josephpconley I am using play 2.0 framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to override `resourceDirectory` so that it picks up the messages file.

```
resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / .. / "conf")
```

In Play 2.2.x/SBT 0.13.x it'd be:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "conf"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.After making the changes suggested by you , page is getting properly loaded from new conf folder.

Comment: Kindly tell me if there is any way by which i can put messages file in some other path and remaining all the files in default conf folder and the application on start up take the messages file from new path and remaining files from default conf path

Comment: @user2800089 Well, I would think you can remove your override for confDirectory and just leave the resourceDirectory line but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Play grabs/copies the messages file(s) at compile time and basically bundles them in with the application. On start the application will read the messages from its classpath, not whatever directory you specified in Build.scala.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20913505/1305344 for the answer (btw, it's your question, @user2800089).

Comment: @estmatic I don't want to put messages file in default conf folder but in some other location.I want that Play should copy those messages file from its new location and bundles them with the application and work normally i.e. as per the language set , it should be able to get the translated text using Messages.get(<key>);

Comment: @estmatic I commented confDirectory <<= baseDirectory(_ / ".." / "conf") and put only resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / .. / "conf") in build.scala but its not working because other files like application-context-xml which is present in default conf folder , its not able to locate them because,now its searching in new location.