# How to set up Play to read message files from a custom directory?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

In `build.scala`, I've changed the path of message files as follows:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "main.less"),
    resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
    resolvers += "maven2 repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
    unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory(_ / ".." / "messagesFiles")
  )
```

The `messagesFiles` folder contains `messages` and `messages.fr` files.

At application startup a translated text is not showing up. Why?

How to set up a play application to read the messages files present in a custom location apart from `conf` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described your environment regarding play version so let me assume you use the recent version Play `2.2.2-RC1`. Mine is...

```
[myFirstApp] $ show playVersion
[info] 2.2.2-RC1
```

Given the play version, you can configure the project using `build.sbt` in most cases. Create one if you don't have it in your project.

Add the following line to `build.sbt` to point at the custom directory where language-specific message files are.

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "messagesFiles"
```

I'm unsure whether it is the most recommended approach to specify the messages directory, but given how sbt works it does the trick.

You can `show` the value of the `unmanagedResourceDirectories` setting as follows:

```
[myFirstApp] $ show unmanagedResourceDirectories
[info] List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/play-ground/myFirstApp/conf, /Users/jacek/sandbox/play-ground/myFirstApp/messagesFiles)
```

The above output assumes the above setting in `build.sbt`.

In the previous versions of Play (and hence SBT) the following in `project/Build.scala` could do the trick:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ / ".." / "messagesFiles" )
```

Comment: I am using Play 2.1.0 version. If i am including this line unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "messagesFiles" in my Build.scala , i am getting error as " value value is not a member of sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]". Beside I am unable to find " unmanagedResourceDirectories " key in this [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSettings)

Comment: Could you edit my answer or comment it with the solution so I'll add what worked for you?

Comment: I have to add below line in settings method of build.scala : unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ /  ".." / "messagesFiles" )

Comment: Thanks! I've added what worked for you so you could approve my answer as the solution.